# Exibir apenas comentários feitos em posts do autor

Tags: php, wordpress

Gostaria de saber como fazer para que este código que achei no fórum do `WordPress` exiba apenas comentários feitos em posts do usuário logado (*author logado*) no `WordPress`.

Quero exibir esta lista no *footer* e já utilizo a função `is_user_logged_in()` no meu *footer*, o porém é fazer o código a seguir listar apenas os comentários recentes dos posts do usuário logado.
Segue o código:

```
<ol class="commentlist">
<?php
    //Gather comments for a specific page/post 
    $comments = get_comments(array(
        'post_id' => XXX,
        'status' => 'approve' //Change this to the type of comments to be displayed
    ));

    //Display the list of comments
    wp_list_comments(array(
        'per_page' => 10, //Allow comment pagination
        'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
    ), $comments);
?>
```

Comment: Adicione mais detalhes à questão. Onde está o seu problema? Não estás conseguindo filtrar os `posts` por usuário? Ou não está conseguindo limitar a quantidade de registros que são trazidos na consulta?

Comment: Será que sua nova pergunta é duplicata desta?